# Send a csv (saved in the solution) to the front end using C# MVC

Tags: c#, csv, model-view-controller, download

I'm new to C# and I'm building a web scraper with a front end using MVC. The application uploads a file of IDs, uses selenium to lookup the uploaded IDs, collects data, then writes it to a CSV. The CSV is then saved within the solution with the file path "./files/output.csv".

The functionality works all the way to writing and saving the output.csv to the solution. **But I can't figure out how to send that CSV back to the user on the front end.** After "./files/output.csv" is written, the controller hits a line that says

```
return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
```

and a simple line of JSON appears on the screen giving count/size/filepath of the uploaded file(s).

Here is my controller

```
public class ScraperController : Controller
{
    private readonly IScraperService _scraperService;

    public ScraperController(IScraperService scraperService)
    {
        _scraperService = scraperService;
    }

    [HttpPost("Scraper")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                List<string> memberIds = _scraperService.Read(filePath);
                List<Result> results = _scraperService.Scrape(memberIds);
                _scraperService.Write(results);
            }
        }

        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**How do I send the newly written .csv back to the user?** Do I need another ActionResult? Do I need another controller? Do I need another view?

Comment: Are you trying to display your data on the front end? Can you just return a file like this? return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(yourFile), "text/csv", "your name.csv");

Comment: Yes, I'd like to just return file that the user can download (or that downloads automatically). I do not need to display the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a file:

```
  return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(yourFile), "text/csv", "yourFileName.csv");
```